# Survival analysis without a direct coupling between subjects and events

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, weibull-distribution, kaplan-meier

I am studying the failure rates of some components. The data that we possess are atypical for a survival analysis, however. The population and year of installation of components are known for the last X years. Another dataset lists the failures that occurred to some components, and an age-interval of the failed component. However, there is no coupling between the failures and the components. I am wondering whether I can still perform some survival analysis techniques such as Kaplan-Meier, the Cox model or Weibull regression.

I can give an example of what the data looks like, written in R. The population data is like:

```
# Population first observation year
pop_table <- data.frame(AGE = 0:102, YEAR1 = c(100:1,0,0,0)*4)

# Remove 200 elements at random, add 400 elements of age 0
set.seed(31415)
population <- rep(1:length(pop_table$YEAR1),times=pop_table$YEAR1)
population <- c(rep(0,400),population[-sample(1:length(population),200)])
pop_table <- cbind(pop_table, YEAR2=c(table(population),0,0))
# Again
population <- rep(1:length(pop_table$YEAR2),times=pop_table$YEAR2)
population <- c(rep(0,400),population[-sample(1:length(population),200)])
pop_table <- cbind(pop_table, YEAR3=c(table(population),0))
# And again
population <- rep(1:length(pop_table$YEAR3),times=pop_table$YEAR3)
population <- c(rep(0,400),population[-sample(1:length(population),200)])
pop_table <- cbind(pop_table, YEAR4=c(table(population)))
```

So for the last four years the number of components for each installation year are known. The removal of a component can be due to a failure, but much more often it is replaced for another reason.
The failure data look like:

```
failures <- data.frame(YEAR = c("YEAR1","YEAR2", "YEAR3", "YEAR4"),
                       "Age0to5" = c(3,2,4,3),
                       "AgeA5to10" = c(2,1,3,2),
                       "Age10to20" = c(4,6,3,5),
                       "Age20to40" = c(9,9,11,10),
                       "Age40to60" = c(11,12,12,12),
                       "Age60+" = c(10,12,11,13))
```

Thus my data is certainly left truncated and right censored, probably also interval-censored. But how do I deal with the fact that there is no direct coupling between the subjects and the events? Are survival analysis techniques still of any use?

Comment: @Carl, this isn't self study, & for posts that are, we try not to add the tag for the OP, but ask them to add it themselves & read its wiki. (There is example text [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2486/7290).) That way there is a better chance they will be familiar w/ our policies, & if they don't add the tag, that's a signal & we can close the thread.